# button should refer to itself in C#

Tags: c#

Assuming there are buttons with all the letters from the alphabet set as Text.
I want to call a function in these buttons and use this letter as argument.
Can I use the same piece of code for each button in some way?

something like

```
functionname(this.Text);
```

Problem is, that "this" referrs to the Form and not to the specific button.

Comment: More information, please: are you using Windows Forms or WPF or something else altogether?  Maybe provide some code samples of waht you've already tried.

Comment: Also, what triggers the calling of this function? E.g. is it the button being clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most event mechanisms you can obtain the *source* of the event; in classic win forms vents this is typically called "sender". You can cast the sender to what you know it is, or some common base-type. For example:

```
void SomeEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e) {
    string text = ((Control)sender).Text;
    // ...
}
```

Hence with this a single event-handler can handle all the buttons.

This may vary subtly between infrastructure / tools (WCF, XNA etc) but fundamentally should remain similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try an event handler like this:

```
protected button1_click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) {
    var button1 = (Button) sender;
    if (button1.Text == "A") {
        //for example
    }
}
```

You will then need to add the event handler, either in "on load" using `AddHandler...` or if it's an Asp.net page you can use the `onClick="button1_click"` attribute.

For a more specific answer, I would need some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same event handler for every button on the form:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.Click += AllButtonClick;
    }
}

private void AllButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    String buttonText = btn.Text;
}
```